# what should i do if my css is not working while i am using django framework?

Tags: html, css, django, django-templates, django-static

In main html document:

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{STATIC_URL}}sgbit/style.css" media="screen" >
    <title>sgbit</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

in settings.py file:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR , 'static'),
]
```

I'm trying basic background color change to confirm css is working on my document, but nothing i try seems to work. I have watched a lot of youtube videos and also read the documents several times. can you please tell me the issues in my code.

Comment: Can you show the directory structure and the directory in which you have the css files?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'sgbit/style.css'%} " media="screen" >
    <title>sgbit</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```